# Maven Invalid maximum heap size error -Xmx4g on mahout-math-scala_2.10

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, mahout, heap-size

I am trying to install mahout through maven but i get Invalid maximum heap size error:
[heap size error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md02o.png)

```
--- scalatest-maven-plugin:1.0:test (test) @ mahout-math-scala_2.10 ---
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit
```

I am using 64 bit laptop and 32 bit ubuntu 16.04 os on virtual box. This is full error stack trace:

```
Failed to execute goal org.scalatest:scalatest-maven-plugin:1.0:test (test) on project mahout-math-scala_2.10: There are test failures -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.scalatest:scalatest-maven-plugin:1.0:test (test) on project mahout-math-scala_2.10: There are test failures
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures
    at org.scalatest.tools.maven.TestMojo.execute(TestMojo.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :mahout-math-scala_2.10
```

Comment: You seemed to be using a 32 Bit JVM where you need a 64 Bit version.

Comment: what version of maven are you  using? mahout requires > maven 3.3.3, the stable is 3.3.9 now.

Comment: I was using maven3.3.9 and I thought I needed a 64 bit version. Now I have a 64 bit ubuntu 16.04 os but ı have an different error. And says cannot find the symbol for mahout.math 

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project mahout-math: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)